# What exactly is the difference between dependency pull and contextualised dependency lookup?

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

I don't understand the exact difference between the dependency pull and contextualised dependency lookup.

From what I understand, dependency pull involves gathering dependencies from a registry ( source of resources).

Contextualised dependency lookup involves gathering dependencies from container not from the registry.

If we use applicationcontext, it is a container right ? then if I use getbean() to get resource would it be considered as contextualised dependency lookup? And what about dependency pull ? Isn't applicationcontext consists of collection of resources?

So what are the examples for both and how they justify the definition?